# How did Saul Die- The Amalekite claims to have killed him

Tags: death, samuel-shmuel-book-of, emes-truth-honesty, king-saul

In Book 2 of Shmuel chapter 1 The Amalekite that tells David of Sauls death.
Did the Amalekite that claimed to have killed Saul tell that to David for his prestige?
Why did he claim to have killed him?
did he in fact kill him (finish him off) or was this a complete lie?